Shell - send characters without a newline (or have unbuffered lines?)
I'm using a program that expects to be able to read a character from the terminal as soon as it's pressed - i.e. presumably sets the terminal options so it's unbuffered*.
I don't seem to be able to get emacs's shell mode to be able to send just a character without a newline - e.g. to send a as opposed to a\n.
Any thoughts on how to get around this without stepping outside emacs and using a regular terminal?
* I know the best option would be to modify the program to accommodate other terminals, but I'd like something that works sooner rather than later

C-c C-d is bound to comint-send-eof which is the equivalent of typing C-d at a "normal" terminal. That should dispatch the current contents of the input buffer to whoever is waiting for input. Note that a second C-c C-d (or C-d at a "normal" terminal) would send an EOF with the input buffer empty which would normally terminate most programs.

shell is a shell, not a terminal. If you need terminal features, such as uncooked input, then use term instead.

I'm accepting @NickD's answer, added here so I can mark it as such:

C-c C-d is bound to comint-send-eof which is the equivalent of typing C-d at a "normal" terminal. That should dispatch the current contents of the input buffer to whoever is waiting for input. Note that a second C-c C-d (or C-d at a "normal" terminal) would send an EOF with the input buffer empty which would normally terminate most programs.

